# Extending DisplayTemplates

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I currently have a (working) DisplayTemplate that looks like this:

```
@model string
@{
    string icon = "tasks";
    string colour = "red";
    string title = "Not Started, Set or Looked at Yet";

    switch (Model)
    {
        case "None":
            icon = "ban-circle";
            colour = "green";
            title = "Chosen not to be implemented";
            break;
        case "Implemented":
            icon = "check";
            colour = "green";
            title = "Implemented";
            break;
        case "Unable to Implement":
            icon = "remove-circle";
            colour = "green";
            title = "Unable to Implement for Technical or Contract Reasons";
            break;
    }

    <span class="glyphicon glyphiconbig glyphicon-@icon @colour" title="@title"></span>
}
```

This works fine. In the page where this code is being instantiated, I am generating a table and looping through with a foreach. What I want to do is insert some other data from my model into here. If I was just in the page I could do:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Comment)
```

That's not possible in the DisplayTemplate (and I tried messing with the model syntax in the display template but I just broke things). How can I best achieve that in the DisplayTemplate?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: There's an [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff406523%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) for DisplayFor that accepts `additionalData` (which would be a great opportunity to pass more information to your DisplayTemplate.)

Comment: Brad, I'm not sure I follow - can you give an example? As I can't reference the current model iteration in the display template?

Comment: Oh, you're trying to back-reference the model from the DisplayTemplate?

Comment: Indeed! Specifically I want to write an alt attribute onto my span but not sure how to access the model from the displaytemplate.

Comment: You wouldn't, you'd call something like `@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Comment, new { alt = Model.AltText })` Then access `ViewData["alt"]` in your display template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given more detail, passing alt text is easy using the [`additionalViewData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff406482%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) overload of `Html.DisplayFor`

So, we have our view model...

```
class MyViewModel
{
    [UIHint("CommentIcon")]
    public String Comment { get; set; }
}
```

Which gets passed to our view...

```
@model MyViewModel
@* Other Stuff *@
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Comment, new { alt = "Comment Alt Test" });
```

In our display template (`~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/CommentIcon.cshtml`):

```
@model string
@{
  string alt = ((String)ViewData["alt"]) ?? String.Empty;
  string icon = "tasks";
  string colour = "red";
  string title = "Not Started, Set or Looked at Yet";

  switch (Model)
  {
    case "None":
      icon = "ban-circle";
      colour = "green";
      title = "Chosen not to be implemented";
      break;
    case "Implemented":
      icon = "check";
      colour = "green";
      title = "Implemented";
      break;
    case "Unable to Implement":
      icon = "remove-circle";
      colour = "green";
      title = "Unable to Implement for Technical or Contract Reasons";
      break;
  }

  <span class="glyphicon glyphiconbig glyphicon-@icon @colour" title="@title" alt="@alt"></span>
}
```

You could also build the `<span>` dynamically using `TagBuilder` if you wanted to leave off `alt` attribute if it isn't supplied.

As far as accessing the original model, you wouldn't. This would create a tight coupling of your display template and a specific model. Remember, you want these views to be self-contained and server only a single [reusable] purpose.

Comment: This was spot on Brad, thanks - sometimes it just helps to have that second set of eyes! I am assuming your : String.Empty syntax is C#6 as it wouldn't work in my code but was able to remediate anyway.

Comment: Oops, should have been `??`. Brain fart, though I'll just say it was C#6. ;-)